# About dialog for html page in SWT application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an about dialog in `Swing` that uses a `JEditorPane` to display an `html` document (`setContentType("text/html");`).
I want to creat an about dialog in an Eclipse SWT application and display this same `html` document which will be displayed formatted (hyperlinks, br etc) same as it did in `Swing`.
How could I do this? What is the appropriate widget? `StyledText`?
I started with a `Browser` in a `Handler`:

```
@Execute
    public void execute(final Shell currentShell){  
      //load html file in textReader
        Browser browser = new Browser(currentShell, SWT.NONE);  
        browser.setText(textReader.toString());  
    }
```

But nothing is displayed. What is the proper way to resolve this?

**Update:** Tested @Baz change:

```
@Execute
    public void execute(final Shell currentShell){  
        currentShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());  
        //load html file in textReader  
        Browser browser = new Browser(currentShell, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setText(textReader.toString());
        currentShell.pack();
}
```

It completelly ruins the application! The html is loaded covering the existing elements

Comment: It's hard to tell why nothing is shown with just this code sample. Are you displaying the browser in a `Dialog`? Where does the `Shell` come from? `StyledText` currently cannot be fed with HTML.

Comment: @Baz:I have associated a `Handler` with a command for a menu item defined in `Application.e4xmi`.The handler i.e. the above `execute` method is called when I press the button.What other code would I needed to put in the post for this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Just realised that this is an Eclipse4 feature that I didn't know yet. Can't test it here myself, but maybe try setting a `FillLayout` on the `Shell` or maybe call `pack()` after adding the `Browser`.

Comment: @Baz:Check update!Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Did you try using either of the suggestions rather than both at the same time?

Comment: @Baz:Yes I tried `pack()` also. It affects my main application but and shrinks it but no browser is displayed

Comment: @Baz:Just found this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-swing2swt/section5.html which implies that `JeditorPane` is replaced by `StyledText`.Is this wrong?

Comment: No, that's not wrong, but the `StyledText` is not able to display HTML by itself. You would have to "parse" that manually. As you can see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-swing2swt/section5.html#JEditorPane).

Comment: @Baz:Let's try to simplify this.Is there an `About Dialog` component to be used?(hopefully not from nebula.....) ;)

Comment: You can simply extend the JFace `Dialog` and add your browser there. Let me post a simple example for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the good old JFace `Dialog` with an embedded `Browser` widget:

```
public class BrowserDialog extends Dialog {

    private String browserString;

    protected BrowserDialog(Shell parentShell, String browserString) {
        super(parentShell);
        this.browserString = browserString;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        composite.setLayout(layout);

        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        data.widthHint = 400;
        data.heightHint = 400;
        composite.setLayoutData(data);


        Browser browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setText(browserString);
        browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        return composite;
    }

    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("About");
    }

    @Override
    public void okPressed() {
        close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        Color gray = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND);

        String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", gray.getRed(), gray.getGreen(), gray.getBlue());

        new BrowserDialog(shell, "<body bgcolor='" + hex + "'><h2>TEXT</h2></body>").open();
    }

}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

If you want the dialog buttons, just replace the `createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)` method with this:

```
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    createButton(parent, Dialog.OK, "OK", true);
    createButton(parent, Dialog.CANCEL, "Cancel", false);
}
```

Then it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: `Composite content = new Composite(currentShell);` does not compile

Comment: @Cratylus Edited answer again. Next try ;)

Comment: This worked. Did it slightly different.I extended `TitleAreaDialog` instead since haven't used `Dialog` so far and did not want to potentially mix eclipse3 and eclipse 4 components(am I wrong?).

Comment: @Cratylus As you can see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FTitleAreaDialog.html) `TitleAreaDialog` is a subclass of `Dialog`. There is nothing wrong with using the `Dialog` instead. But if you prefer `TitleAreaDialog`, go ahead and use it.

Comment: Using `Dialog` do I also get `OK`-`Cancel`?In your screenshot I don't see them.

Comment: @Cratylus If you want to have them, yo can have them. Depends on what you do inside the `createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)`. Let me post an example with buttons (although I don't understand why an about dialog needs two buttons).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!I am new in Eclipse programming and I haven't a good grasp of the concepts yet.Is it me or is the programming model hard?

Comment: @Cratylus SWT is quite different from Swing, so the migration is quite hard. But once you got to know the concept, it is pretty nice to use. As for the RCP stuff: reading lots of tutorials really helped me, although I cannot verify this for Eclipse e4.